# I'm trying to replace all crafted Iron Chestplates with Chain Mail ones for a hard survival multiplayer world

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

My initial idea was to detect when an Iron Chestplate is applied to the armor.chest inventory slot and to use /replaceitem to turn it to chainmail. I am not skilled enough with /execute /replaceitem /scoreboard /data or any higher level commands for any of this. Any ideas?

Comment: Your best bet here would probably just be to get a resource pack that makes iron armour look like chain mail, but you'd still have the same stats as iron at that point. I'm not at all skilled with complex commands, so I'm not sure I could help you there.

Comment: You can probably overwrite the recipe with a datapack. Interestingly, the wiki does not mention at all whether you can overwrite Vanilla recipes, but I assume you can.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command in a repeat Command Block (1.13+):

`/execute as @a[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:102b,id:"minecraft:iron_chestplate"}]}] run replaceitem entity @s armor.chest minecraft:chainmail_chestplate 1`

However, this will only work once the Iron Chestplate is placed in the player's armor slot.

Comment: Thank you very much! this was exactly what i needed

Comment: No Problem :) I Would appreciate if you marked it as Answer. Because I'm new and trying to get some reputation.